# How To Let Users Customize Javascript and CSS File, then export as Embed Code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im interested in starting a small service where users can sign into a dashboard, customize, and then export a age verification pop up for their site. I've downloaded a base file to work off of:

```js
/*!
 * Simple Age Verification (https://github.com/Herudea/age-verification))
 */

var modal_content,
modal_screen;

// Start Working ASAP.
$(document).ready(function() {
 av_legality_check();
});


av_legality_check = function() {
 if ($.cookie('is_legal') == "yes") {
  // legal!
  // Do nothing?
 } else {
  av_showmodal();

  // Make sure the prompt stays in the middle.
  $(window).on('resize', av_positionPrompt);
 }
};

av_showmodal = function() {
 modal_screen = $('<div id="modal_screen"></div>');
 modal_content = $('<div id="modal_content" style="display:none"></div>');
 var modal_content_wrapper = $('<div id="modal_content_wrapper" class="content_wrapper"></div>');
 var modal_regret_wrapper = $('<div id="modal_regret_wrapper" class="content_wrapper" style="display:none;"></div>');

 // Question Content
 var content_heading = $('<h2>Are you 21 or older?</h2>');
 var content_buttons = $('<nav><ul><li><a href="#nothing" class="av_btn av_go" rel="yes">Yes</a></li><li><a href="#nothing" class="av_btn av_no" rel="no">No</a></li></nav');
 var content_text = $('<p>You must verify that you are 21 years of age or older to enter this site.</p>');

 // Regret Content
 var regret_heading = $('<h2>We\'re Sorry!</h2>');
 var regret_buttons = $('<nav><small>I hit the wrong button!</small> <ul><li><a href="#nothing" class="av_btn av_go" rel="yes">I\'m old enough!</a></li></ul></nav');
 var regret_text = $('<p>You must be 21 years of age or older to enter this site.</p>');

 modal_content_wrapper.append(content_heading, content_buttons, content_text);
 modal_regret_wrapper.append(regret_heading, regret_buttons, regret_text);
 modal_content.append(modal_content_wrapper, modal_regret_wrapper);

 // Append the prompt to the end of the document
 $('body').append(modal_screen, modal_content);

 // Center the box
 av_positionPrompt();

 modal_content.find('a.av_btn').on('click', av_setCookie);
};

av_setCookie = function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

 var is_legal = $(e.currentTarget).attr('rel');

 $.cookie('is_legal', is_legal, {
  expires: 30,
  path: '/'
 });

 if (is_legal == "yes") {
  av_closeModal();
  $(window).off('resize');
 } else {
  av_showRegret();
 }
};

av_closeModal = function() {
 modal_content.fadeOut();
 modal_screen.fadeOut();
};

av_showRegret = function() {
 modal_screen.addClass('nope');
 modal_content.find('#modal_content_wrapper').hide();
 modal_content.find('#modal_regret_wrapper').show();
};

av_positionPrompt = function() {
 var top = ($(window).outerHeight() - $('#modal_content').outerHeight()) / 2;
 var left = ($(window).outerWidth() - $('#modal_content').outerWidth()) / 2;
 modal_content.css({
  'top': top,
  'left': left
 });

 if (modal_content.is(':hidden') && ($.cookie('is_legal') != "yes")) {
  modal_content.fadeIn('slow')
 }
};
```

```css
/*!
 * Age verification CSS to go with the JS that can be found at (https://github.com/Herudea/age-verification)
 */

#modal_screen {
 position: fixed;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1100;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
}

#modal_screen.nope {
 background-color: #1e0924; 
}

#modal_content {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1101;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color:#fff;
 border:4px solid #444;
 border-radius: 100%;
 font-size: 12px;
 width:290px;
 height: 290px;

 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 -o-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;

 background-position: center 2em;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 90px auto;
 background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

#modal_content .content_wrapper {
 padding-top: 8em;
 margin:3em auto 0;
 text-align: center;
}

#modal_content h2 {
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 font:normal 15px/1.3em 'Gill Sans W01 Medium', Helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
}

#modal_content p {
 max-width: 75%;
 margin: 1.2em auto 0;
 font:11px/1.5em "proxima-nova", Helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
}

#modal_content nav {font-size: 16px; display:table; width: 282px;}
#modal_content nav ul {display:table-row; width: 100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
#modal_content nav li {display: table-cell; text-align: right; width: auto;}

#modal_content nav:after {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 clear: both;
}

#modal_content nav small {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 color: #888;
 margin: 1em 0 0;
}

#modal_content nav a.av_btn {
 display:block;
 text-align:center;
 width: 65px;
 border-radius: 23px;
 margin:1em auto 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding:1em;
 color: #fff;
 font:normal .7em/1em 'AmericanTypwrterITCW01- 731031';
 text-transform: none;
 letter-spacing: 0;
}

#modal_content nav .av_go {
 background-color: #7fbf4d;
}

#modal_content nav .av_no {
 background-color: #938d95;
}

#modal_content nav .av_btn:hover {
 background-color: #1e0924;
}

#modal_content #modal_regret_wrapper nav a.av_btn {
 margin-top:0;
 width:130px;
 font-size: 0.8em;
}

@media (min-width: 688px) {
 #modal_content {
  top: 10em;
  top: 30vh;
  left: 30vw;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height:500px;
  padding:3em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-position: center 3em;
  background-size: 160px auto;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

 #modal_content .content_wrapper {
  padding-top: 150px;
  margin:3em auto 0;
  text-align: center;
 }

 #modal_content h2 {
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  font-size: 1.875em;
 }

 #modal_content p {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.9em;
 }

 #modal_content nav {width: 396px;}

 #modal_content nav a.av_btn {
  padding:1em 2.5em;
  margin:1.6em auto 0;
  font-size: 1em;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Age Verification Demo</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/round-about.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Age Verification CSS -->
    <link href="css/age-verification.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim for HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Introduction Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">About Us
                    <small>It's Nice to Meet You!</small>
                </h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, explicabo dolores ipsam aliquam inventore corrupti eveniet quisquam quod totam laudantium repudiandae obcaecati ea consectetur debitis velit facere nisi expedita vel?</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Team Members Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h2 class="page-header">Our Team</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
                <h3>John Smith
                    <small>Job Title</small>
                </h3>
                <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
                <h3>John Smith
                    <small>Job Title</small>
                </h3>
                <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
                <h3>John Smith
                    <small>Job Title</small>
                </h3>
                <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
                <h3>John Smith
                    <small>Job Title</small>
                </h3>
                <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
                <h3>John Smith
                    <small>Job Title</small>
                </h3>
                <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 text-center">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive img-center" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
                <h3>John Smith
                    <small>Job Title</small>
                </h3>
                <p>What does this team member to? Keep it short! This is also a great spot for social links!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/age-verification.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make it where users can change these attributes in a dashboard and then export that finished code as an embed code?

(note: I understand my question isn't very specific for one main problem)

Comment: You would need a **database** to store the user inputs, and a **back-end** language to interact with the server (such as PHP or C#). You would query the database to find the user's preference, and insert the user's variables into the appropriate output files based on the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<textarea>` element for visitor to upload, paste, or set their code at the element using JavaScript.

Create a `data URI` of the original or edited content, use `<a>` element with `download` attribute or `window.open()` to offer user file for download.

```css
textarea {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea data-type="text/html" data-file-name="document.html" class="html"><!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script>console.log("abc")</script></head><body>HTML</body></html></textarea><button>save</button><br>
<textarea data-type="text/css" data-file-name="document.css"  class="css">body {color:blue}</textarea><button>save</button><br>
<textarea data-type="text/javascript" data-file-name="document.js" class="javascript">console.log(123)</textarea><button>save</button><br>
<script>
$("button").on("click", function() {
  var content = $(this).prev("textarea");
  var dataURI = `data:${content.data().type},${content.val()}`;
  var a = $("<a>", {
    download: content.data().fileName,
    href: dataURI,
    on: {click: function() {this.remove()}}
  }).appendTo(document.body)[0];
  a.click()
})
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to generate an embed code or iframe for those files made instead of downloading them?

Comment: @JakeMurdoc Yes, using code at Answer. The code is valid HTML, CSS, JavaScript code. You can pass `content.data().type` to `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the plain text, if that is necessary. `dataURI` variable is a valid `data URI`